# Question in time period of oscillation of a ball in bowl

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, oscillators

We know time period of pendulum is $$T=2\pi\sqrt{\frac{L}{g}}$$

While reading through a question on S.E which was based on a ball oscillating on a bowl , I was curious and I thought of its time period as the time period of a pendulum bob which is under oscillation by gravity , So I naively thought the time period would be $$T=2\pi\sqrt{\frac{R}{g}}$$

> Given g=acceleration due to gravity of earth R= Radius of bowl

However The actual answer was given in my book and websites :

$$T=2\pi\sqrt{\frac{R-r}{g}}$$

> Where R is the radius of the bowl (so it acts like an imaginary string) and r is the radius of ball and R>>r

So what perplexes me is The Length L as I have learnt also includes the radius of bob as the effective tension of wire acts on the center of mass of bob ( approximation we make bob to be uniform) so $L_{effective}= L_{wire}+r_{bob}$

Why doesn't this apply to the ball problem whereas its a given in pendulum ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bob is an essential part of the pendulum, so people include the length of the bob as a natural part of the length of the whole pendulum. On the other hand, a ball and a bowl aren't usually thought of as a single system, but as two objects interacting. So, the physics problem is defined in terms of the separate geometry of the two items.

This is just an issue of how a person can group together objects in their mind.

Comment: Thats an interesting perspective , thank you!